# Can we get build data like build_url , jenkins_home , jenkins_url, build_time etc via Jenkins build console logs?

Tags: jenkins, logging

Does logs generated by Jenkins console output contain these type of information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variables to get this information:
1) **BUILD_URL** to get the build url
2) **JENKINS_HOME** to get jenkins home folders path
3) **JENKINS_URL** to get jenkins url

If you want to print build url on console then do this: **echo "Build url is ${BUILD_URL}**"
Same applies to other environment variables as well.